# Cat and mouse are doing a random walk on nonbipartite connected graph G. Show that exp. time for C to catch M is bounded by $|E(G)|^2|V(G)|$

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

I am trying to solve this exercise and am having trouble starting. The cat and mouse all move at the same time in discrete time steps. The cat catches the mouse when both are at the same location at the same time. I tried solving this by using a markov chain and  trying to use some bounds on the expected time to cover the whole graph. But I am getting nowhere.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: These slides (www.lirmm.fr/~sau/JCALM/Josep.pdf) deal with random walks on graphs (hitting time etc) in spectral terms: thay should be enough to provide you a better bound.

Comment: For a simple combinatorial approach, one may consider that the expected value is just the sum over $n$ of the probabilities $p(n)$ that $C$ and $M$ never met in the first $n$ steps. If we are able to approximate $p(n+1)$ in terms of $p(n)\cdot(1-\kappa)$, the previous series is a geometric series converging to $\frac{1}{\kappa}$.

Comment: Now assume that $C$ and $M$ do not meet in the first $n$ steps, but they meet at the $(n+1)$-th step. They both arrive at some vertex by following two different edges: this should be the key point for the appearance of $E^2 V$.